# Matplotlib - Line connecting points incorrectly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting via matplotlib/pyplot. Why the initial points (blue) of star and circle are connecting a line to the final points? Initial point star is connecting the final point circle, and the initial point circle is connecting the final point square.

This is the source code:

```
plt.plot(x,y, color="black")
plt.errorbar(x1,y1,yerr=err1,marker='s', markersize="10", mfc='blue', color='blue',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x2,y2,yerr=err2,marker='s', markersize="10", mfc='green', color='green',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x3,y3,yerr=err3,marker='s', markersize="10", mfc='red', color='red',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x4,y4,yerr=err4,marker='s', markersize="10", mfc='yellow', color='yellow',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x5,y5,yerr=err5,marker='s', markersize="10", mfc='orange', color='orange',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x6,y6,yerr=err6,marker='s', markersize="10", mfc='purple', color='purple',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x7,y7,yerr=err7,marker='s', markersize="10", mfc='magenta', color='magenta',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x8,y8,yerr=err8,marker='s', markersize="10", mfc='cyan', color='cyan',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x9,y9,yerr=err9,marker='o', markersize="10", mfc='blue', color='blue',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x10,y10,yerr=err10,marker='o', markersize="10", mfc='green', color='green',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x11,y11,yerr=err11,marker='o', markersize="10", mfc='red', color='red',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x12,y12,yerr=err12,marker='o', markersize="10", mfc='yellow', color='yellow',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x13,y13,yerr=err13,marker='o', markersize="10", mfc='orange', color='orange',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x14,y14,yerr=err14,marker='o', markersize="10", mfc='purple', color='purple',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x15,y15,yerr=err15,marker='o', markersize="10", mfc='magenta', color='magenta',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x16,y16,yerr=err16,marker='o', markersize="10", mfc='cyan', color='cyan',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x17,y17,yerr=err17,marker='*', markersize="10", mfc='blue', color='blue',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x18,y18,yerr=err18,marker='*', markersize="10", mfc='green', color='green',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x19,y19,yerr=err19,marker='*', markersize="10", mfc='red', color='red',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x20,y20,yerr=err20,marker='*', markersize="10", mfc='yellow', color='yellow',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x21,y21,yerr=err21,marker='*', markersize="10", mfc='orange', color='orange',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x22,y22,yerr=err22,marker='*', markersize="10", mfc='purple', color='purple',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x23,y23,yerr=err23,marker='*', markersize="10", mfc='magenta', color='magenta',fmt = '')
plt.errorbar(x24,y24,yerr=err24,marker='*', markersize="10", mfc='cyan',   color='cyan',fmt = '')
plt.savefig("image.png",bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

"x" variable is a shape 24 array.
"y" variable is a shape 24 array
"err" variables, are just real numbers.

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have three series of data, one for the square points, one for the round points and one for the star points. If that is the case, you have to plot these three series separately, while right now you do that at once (as you said, you have two arrays of length 24). Try splitting your plot command into three like this: first `plot(x[0:8],y[0:8],'black)` then `plot(x[8:16],y[8:16],'black')` and then `plot(x[16:24],y[16:24],'black')` -- this should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks! Post it as a answer, please, then I will mark as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot three separate lines of eight points each, you cannot plot them 'at once' using two arrays of length 24. Instead, split your data into three separate peaces and plot them separately:

```
plot(x[0:8],y[0:8],'black')
plot(x[8:16],y[8:16],'black')
plot(x[16:24],y[16:24],'black')
```

This should do the trick. Note also, that you can shorten your `errorbar` code considerably by using `lists` and `for` statements. For instance you could do

```
errs = [err1,err2,err3,err4,err5,err6,err7,err8] #probably you did have these in a list or array anyway
cols = ['b','g','r','y','orange','purple','m','c']

for i,(errval,col) in enumerate(zip(errs,cols)): 
     plt.errorbar(x[i],y[i],yerr=errvall, marker='s', markersize="10", mfc=col, color=col,fmt = '')
```

with another `for` loop you could still loop through the `markers`. Hope this helps.